# IsPostback=false even though Request.HttpMethod is "POST"?

Tags: asp.net, routes, url-rewriting, viewstate

I've recently been hacking with webforms seeing if it's possible to use one of my (routing) projects with it. So far, it's been nothing but trouble, but I'm almost to the point that it "works"

I made a page "Test.aspx". At Global.asax, I made it so that it's served at `/test` instead of `/Test.aspx`. This works completely. It descends from a custom page class of mine. The custom class finds HtmlForms in the page and rewrites their Action attribute with the proper value: `/test`.

Now I hit the great brick wall titled Viewstate and ASP.Net events. I added a button to Test.aspx with an OnClick handler. I can click the button, and the page will postback and such, but the OnClick event will not occur. I'm not understanding how a simple URL change can break viewstate like this, as I was not under the impression that Viewstate would track such a thing. Also, IsPostback will be false, even though HttpMethod==true. This is not making any sense to me.

Also, I've disabled EventValidation because I figured that'd be trouble, but this problem persists.

How can I make viewstate and postbacks work as usual when rewriting URLs?

(Note, my form of URL rewriting does all rewriting internally, there is never a HTTP redirect sent to the user)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to tell the HttpContext that the URL is being rewritten as well.

Try doing something like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("/test");
```

Comment: This does nothing, unfortunately. Though, I believe it makes my form-rewrite code pointless, so that's kinda a good thing.

Comment: This apparently only replaces my form-rewrite code if done after page_load

Answer (score 0):

The IsPostBack is used for check whether the request is from the control of the page itself.

And the HttpMethod is used for check the request type.